# Regarding Tpot deployed on VM

Tags: virtual-machine, honeypot, tpot

I just wanted to comfirm this small thing we deployed tpot on azure cloud VM and tpot is honeypot it attracts the attackers to attack on that VM and if there will be large amounts of attacks then there will be any issue with your policy because we are planning to subscribe for pay as you go plan and one more thing my VM should not be blocked or deleted?